# Posting a collection to MVC3 from Plupload

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, collections, model-binding, plupload

I've got a documents **upload** page in an **MVC3** application that lets the user upload documents to be **stored in a database** and associated with a parent entity in the database. There are also some permissions that the user can customize to stipulate who can access the document.

I've implemented my document upload functionality with **[Plupload](http://www.plupload.com)**, The behavior that it's working with is that essentially it will take a queue of files, and upload them for me to a specific action dedicated to recieving this information, and when they are posted each file is given a unique name (something like `p16kearti61rf31qb61fogjm2127i3.jpg` for example.)

Once all of the files have been uploaded in plupload, the parent form is submitted with the information about the files plupload just uploaded as well as some other data for the documents like the Primary Key of the object they are to be associated with, and the groups that have been checked off for it's permissions aspect. Now this works fine except that I can't find a strongly typed object structure that MVC will bind my data to so that I can work with the posted back data. **Here's an idea of what is in my Request.Form collection**, what I'm looking for is some insight on how to best capture this information in my action. I have complete control over the naming of the controls for the document permissions, but the plupload controls are built in and I'd don't know if I can change them.

```
__RequestVerificationToken: "...XDsBA5oZA9Ku2oPPdyyi2J+DbvoKRY9HJ2...etc"
ownerId: "CCEE2ADF-633D-4D55-90EE-2829D352BEEB"
uploader_0_tmpname: "p16kearti61rf31qb61fogjm2127i3.jpg"
uploader_0_name: "picture1.jpg"
uploader_0_status: "done"
uploader_1_tmpname: "p16kearti61kqu8tsmja67911v44.jpg"
uploader_1_name: "picture2.jpg"
uploader_1_status: "done"
uploader_2_tmpname: "p16kebp785gci1e291i543cc1c8k4.jpg"
uploader_2_name: "picture3.jpg"
uploader_2_status: "done"
uploader_count: "3"
documentGroups[B8C97C5C-B1B8-43C2-89F1-B1DF353AF677]: "false"
documentGroups[A2C8331C-7068-4611-82BF-6F0C61C8BA7D]: "false"
documentGroups[6DCBF4A8-B863-49E6-AAE9-2A0E372FF622]: "true"
documentGroups[05C04E05-D7A8-45D6-8138-2FA36F0A5922]: "false"
documentGroups[3E2F2B1B-FAAA-420A-B9A1-F223ADF66AF0]: "true"
```

Any suggestions on how to write my action method? I was hoping for something like this but I can't get it to work.

```
public ActionResult Upload(Guid ownerId, IList<PluploadFile> uploader, IList<bool> documentGroups)
```

Comment: Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone else was looking for an update on this (and since I got no response to my question what-so-ever), I ended up splitting my post into two; one handled by plUpload which I use to save the file(s) to a temp folder using the unique names pased in to the Action from plUpload (such as p16kearti61rf31qb61fogjm2127i3.jpg), and the other when I post the wrapping form which holds the information I need and the unique names plupload has as well as some fields indicating the status result of the original upload. The problem is that because it's two posts I now have to look at maintaining the contents of my temp folder in case the user uploads documents but doesn't submit the wrapping form. Not the solution I wanted but I can't an alternative working as expected.